# How do I capture button click details in Flask/Python to modify the button's 'src' value?

Tags: python, html, flask

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><button id="1" onclick="buttonClicked('1')">1</button><br/><img width="25" height="25" src="1"></td>
      <td><button id="2" onclick="buttonClicked('2')">2</button><br/><img width="25" height="25" src="2"></td>
      <td><button id="3" onclick="buttonClicked('3')">3</button><br/><img width="25" height="25" src="3"></td>
      <td><button id="4" onclick="buttonClicked('4')">4</button><br/><img width="25" height="25" src="4"></td>
      <td><button id="5" onclick="buttonClicked('5')">5</button><br/><img width="25" height="25" src="5"></td>
      <td><button id="6" onclick="buttonClicked('6')">6</button><br/><img width="25" height="25" src="6"></td>
      <td><button id="7" onclick="buttonClicked('7')">7</button><br/><img width="25" height="25" src="7"></td>
      <td><button id="8" onclick="buttonClicked('8')">8</button><br/><img width="25" height="25" src="8"></td>
      <td><button id="9" onclick="buttonClicked('9')">9</button><br/><img width="25" height="25" src="9"></td>
      <td><button id="10" onclick="buttonClicked('10')">10</button><br/><img width="25" height="25" src="10"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('buttonli.html')

@app.route('/button_clicked', methods=['POST'])
def button_clicked():
    selected_button = request.form['button_id']
    
    uploaded_image = request.files['uploaded_image']
    if uploaded_image:
        
        uploaded_image.save(f"resimler/{selected_button}.jpg")

    return 'İşlem tamamlandı'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

First of all, keep in mind that I am new so be gentle, please. What I am trying to do is this: I am trying to get a hold of the user's click on a button so that I can take that info and use it in my project. For example, when user clicked on button 1 then it will get the details of button-1- and change its `src` value with a different picture.

Comment: `buttonClicked('1')` in your html is going to be looking for a javascript function in global the context of the page, not something at a flask route.

Comment: Try adding an element to the bottom of your html `<script>buttonClicked function(id){console.log("hi")}</script>` then inspect the console while you click the buttons.  That might help you get started.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. My basic HTML was like this `<td>2<br/><img id="2" width="25" height="25" src="resimler/2.jpg"></td>`. I implemented JS after some research since I could not achieve this with Python. Also, another thing is I get the click, it shows in terminal like `"[33mGET /image/img4 HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -` I do not know how to store the value and then change the image of the button from a folder.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, congratulations on your progress learning web applications, However, there are a few concepts that seems to need more clarification regarding how the web works.

### Clarification

[Flask](http://flask.palletsprojects.com) is a **server-side** framework that can render HTML templates using [Jinja](http://jinja.palletsprojects.com/) and sends it to the user's browser *( using the `return render_template('buttonli.html')` )*. Once the rendered HTML is sent to the browser as a response, **Flask has no control over it**.

Any further modifications or interactions on the client-side need to be handled using JavaScript. Or by navigating to different URLs through anchor tags. Or maybe using html forms that post data to your endpoint on submission.

### Javascript

using javascript gives you a lot more capabilities since it actually runs on the user's browser.
It can edit the page without calling flask, or call flask, wait for its response and render new elements in the existing page or open a new page.

an example of using JS to change the image on button click without invoking flask:

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><button id="image_1" onclick="buttonClicked('1')">1</button><br/><img id="image1" width="25" height="25" src="1"></td>
      <td><button id="image_2" onclick="buttonClicked('2')">2</button><br/><img id="image2" width="25" height="25" src="2"></td>
      <!-- Add the remaining buttons and images here -->
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script>
  function buttonClicked(buttonId) {
    // Perform any necessary actions here
    var imageId = 'image_' + buttonId;
    var imageElement = document.getElementById(imageId);
    imageElement.src = buttonId + '.jpg'; // Replace with the desired image source, sth like 1.jpg
  }
</script>
```

### Anchor tags

if all you want is simple navigation on button click, you can use anchor tags

> Note: you cannot upload files with anchor tags

Server side:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/button_clicked/<int:button_id>')
def button_clicked(button_id: int):
    # Perform any necessary actions here
    # You can use the button_id to determine which image to display

    return render_template('button_clicked.html', button_id=button_id)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

button_clicked.html

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/button_clicked/1">1</a><br/><img width="25" height="25" src="1"></td>
      <td><a href="/button_clicked/2">2</a><br/><img width="25" height="25" src="2"></td>
      <!-- Add the remaining anchor tags and images here -->
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

what this actually means is that flask renders the index.html using jinja and makes the **hrefs** of the anchor tags so they point to the `button_clicked` endpoint url with the appropriate id, when the user clicks a tag, the browser will call the href and invoke flask to return a new page that is shown to the user. Keep in mind that a new page is returned, you cannot update the existing page using anchors.

Comment: Ibraheem Alyan, thanks a lot for your detailed explanation. I am flattered by the details and the time you put into replying for my question. Respect. I am going to try this implementation. All I am trying to do is that I want to press a button/pixel/image and change it with another.